# How to Update Tkinter Label while looking for keyboard input

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard

I am Trying to make a `tkinter` based Cube Timer Program for which I have done a console based program before I wanted to improve on it by making a GUI for it... I have made some tkinter projects before and I have a decent knowledge of how stuff works the thing is I want the `Label` in the `tkinter` window to update in every second while listening for a spacebar key on press I couldn't figure out a way to do it can someone help me?

```py
def on_press(key):
    global chk,start,end,timer_label
    print('{0} pressed'.format(key))
    if key == Key.space:
        if chk == True:
            end = time.time()
            chk = False
            messagebox.showinfo('Your Time',"Your Time =>"+str(round(end-start,3)))

def on_release(key):
    global chk,start,end,timer_label
    if key == Key.space:
        if chk == False:
            start = time.time()
            chk = True


            
with Listener(on_press=on_press,on_release=on_release) as listener:

    main = tk.Tk()
    main.title("Cube Timer Mark 4 Prototype")
    main.resizable(0,0)

    tk.Label(main, text="Cube Time Mk3 Prototype", font=['Consolas',16]).grid(row = 0,column=0)
    textbox = tk.Text(main,font=['Consolas',20], height = 1,width = 27)
    textbox.grid(row = 1,column=0)
    textbox.insert('1.0',scrambler())
    timer_frame = tk.Frame(main).grid(row=2,column=0)

    global timer_label
    timer_label = tk.StringVar()
    timer_label.set("0.0")
    
    tk.Label(timer_frame,text = timer_label.get()+"s",font=['Consolas',20,'bold'],pady = 25).grid(row = 2,column = 0)
    main.mainloop()
```

This is what I have tried but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You need `main.after` to periodically run a function like updating the label. To listen to keyboard event, you need `main.bind`. See example below.

Enhancement: use `tk.Label(..., textvariable=timer_label)` means the label will automatically update when you set `timer_label`

```
import tkinter as tk

def key_press(event):
    if event.keysym == 'space':
        print('pressed')

def key_release(event):
    if event.keysym == 'space':
        print('released')


def update_label():
    # get the time from the string
    time = float(timer_label.get()[:-1])

    # increment the time and put it back in timer_label
    timer_label.set(str(time+1) + 's')

    # calling this function again 1000ms later, which will call this again 1000ms later, ...
    main.after(1000, update_label)

main = tk.Tk()
main.title("Cube Timer Mark 4 Prototype")
main.resizable(0,0)

tk.Label(main, text="Cube Time Mk3 Prototype", font=['Consolas',16]).grid(row = 0,column=0)
textbox = tk.Text(main,font=['Consolas',20], height = 1,width = 27)
textbox.grid(row = 1,column=0)
#textbox.insert('1.0',scrambler())
timer_frame = tk.Frame(main).grid(row=2,column=0)

timer_label = tk.StringVar()
timer_label.set("0.0s")

# using textvariable, you can simply update timer_label and it will be reflected
tk.Label(timer_frame,textvariable = timer_label ,font=['Consolas',20,'bold'],pady = 25).grid(row = 2,column = 0)

# bind keypress and keyrelease to the functions
main.bind("<KeyPress>", key_press)
main.bind("<KeyRelease>", key_release)

# call update label function for the first time
update_label()
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can remove `global timer_label`, variables defined outside functions are globalized by default.